# Sliding panel with if-statement HOW TO?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, panel, slide

I'm learning jQuery and so I have a lot of problems I run into. I could really use some help at this point because I can't see it through myself.

```
$('li.toggleBtn').click(function(){
    if ($('#panel').css('left') === '0px') {
        $('#panel').animate({ left: '-858' });
        $('li.toggleBtn span').toggleClass("toggleImgClosed");

    } else if ($('#panel').css('left') !== '0px') {
        $('#panel').animate({ right: '-858' });
    } 
});
```

The if-statement works, but the else if does not. 
Any idea? 
Also, what would be the best practice of this kind of thing?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need to repeat the if statement. If a is not b, there's no reason to re-check.

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle demo and more clearly specify what you mean when you say the else-if doesn't work?